# How do i detach this fan from the heatsink?

Tags: fan, heatsink, safely-remove-hardware, amd-cpu

I have no idea of what this method of attaching the fan is called, so I have no way of looking it up. I tried to, but I dont know what to look for, so hopefully, someone can tell me how to do it by looking at the picture.
Also, tell me what its called, so maybe I can find a video of it.

[image: heatsink+fan]

Comment: It might help to say what the heatsink is. And the angle dosen't show us everything. They're called wire fan retention clips

Comment: Fan retention clips, thanks for that! It is from brazil, PCYes Zero K Z3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clips on each side?

Pull towards the camera, reverse for the other side.

[image]

Comment: I'm leaning towards prying it apart on the fan side. But that's like *the worst angle*

Comment: Thanks, actually, after i took the picture, i could, for the first time, actually see how they were attached there lol, i did it, it worked.

Comment: From the pic it looks like the 'ridge' at the left of my rectangle is where it's held. A fingernail under it & pull towards the camera ought to do it, I'd think.

Comment: Ah... crossed in post. Glad you got it. Please feel free to mark this as the accepted answer ;-)